# View Json string as collapsible in splunk using winston loggger

Tags: typescript, next.js, splunk, winston

I'm using [winston logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419941/splunk-query-for-javascript-object-to-json-string) to log my next js application and I'm trying to output a json object. However, when I do so, the json object within the message field is not collapsible because it is interpreted as a string.

[image]

In my code, I am just logging it with JSON stringify. What is the correct way to do this, as the other fields are collapsible?

```
const json = { label: 'Component Props', data: {} };
logger.info(JSON.stringify(json), metaData);
```