# splunk how to extract object to table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

example event

```
{
  "test": {
   "x": "y",
   "a": "b",
   "code": {
     "one" : {
       "two": {
         "c": "d"
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

how can I extract some parts of `code` block and present them as table. example

one | c

I have tried putting together a query but not sure how to extract specific fields

```
| spath
| spath test.code{} output=code
| mvexpand code
```

Comment: Hi User,

That is not a valid json doc. and the Spath command is for structured data formats XML and JSON
Can you share what this data  structure is?

Comment: You can do something simular to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419941/splunk-query-for-javascript-object-to-json-string
but  you would need to alter it to not have the single brackets around the values and support nested objects.

Most likely something is wrong with how your importing the data

Comment: @DanielPrice Unfortunately I cannot share the data but updated the example with raw data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="{
  \"test\": {
   \"x\": \"y\",
   \"a\": \"b\",
   \"code\": {
     \"one\" : {
       \"two\": {
         \"c\": \"d\"
       }
     }
   }
 }
}"
| spath test.code output=code
| table code
| spath input=code
```

the key idea here is the input=code,
Spath command takes input as an option argument for which field to find the json to extract the values from. [Spath link](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Spath)

the results from the example given are:

[image: Results from query]

Comment: thank you, looks like I need to restructure my data for better results

Comment: @user6481062 did you want to field names to be different, curious as to why you need this to be restructured

Comment: I want specific json keys in table.

```one | c```

I cannot hardcode one.two.c since keys are not constant - need to do wildcard match